# TFS Build Definition ASP.Net web applicaton Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebActivatorEx' could not be found

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have an ASP.Net web application that builds and test in Visual Studio 17.  I am trying to create a Build Definition, but I continue to get these errors.  I have tried deleting my Workspace, getting the latest from TFS.  I have then upgraded all the NuGet and performed dotnet restore.  I also tried going into the project and added ****\assemblies to the hints, but that didn’t get it to build in VS17.

The build Directory looks as follows
S
    Solution
    All my nuget packages.

Inside the solution directory
Solution
    Solution
        Solution
        Doc
        SolutionTest
        Solution
        Solution.sln

Inside the solution directory
My Solution files all reside here.

My Artifactory NuGet restore puts the NuGet files in the S directory.  I don’t really see an option to locate them differently.  I found an issue for VS2010, but I am not sure if that is the same issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2516078/visual-studio-2010-build-fails-with-an-error-message-the-referenced-pr

I also looked at [Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyFileVersion' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317152/error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-assemblyfileversion-could-not-be-foun), but there was never an answer how to turn it off.

Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs(6,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebActivatorEx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs(6,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebActivatorEx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs(7,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebActivatorEx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs(7,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebActivatorEx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(2,18): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(2,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(3,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Unity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Unity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs(4,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Unity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityMvcActivator.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Unity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(5,19): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Dynamic' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Linq' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(5,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Dynamic' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Linq' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Global.asax.cs(8,18): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Global.asax.cs(8,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(9,44): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(9,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\FilterConfig.cs(9,50): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\FilterConfig.cs(9,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(64,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(64,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(85,82): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(85,82): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(24,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnityContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(24,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnityContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(37,42): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnityContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(37,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnityContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(13,29): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnityContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(13,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IUnityContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(19,44): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Controller' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(19,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Controller' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(95,51): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionExecutingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(95,51): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionExecutingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(133,19): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JsonResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(133,19): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JsonResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(141,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(141,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(148,24): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RedirectResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(148,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RedirectResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(95,33): Error CS0115: 'BaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)': no suitable method found to override
Controllers\BaseController.cs(95,33): error CS0115: 'BaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)': no suitable method found to override [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(140,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandleErrorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(140,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandleErrorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\BaseController.cs(140,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandleError' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\BaseController.cs(140,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandleError' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(8,44): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionFilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(8,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionFilterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(17,6): Error CS0616: 'NoCacheAttribute' is not an attribute class
Controllers\FileController.cs(17,6): error CS0616: 'NoCacheAttribute' is not an attribute class [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(39,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(39,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(61,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JsonResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(61,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JsonResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(98,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(98,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(122,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(122,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(183,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(183,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(261,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(261,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PartialViewResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(367,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(367,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs(22,55): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs(22,55): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs(22,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs(22,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvcHtmlString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(60,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(60,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(60,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(60,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(97,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(97,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(97,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(97,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(121,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(121,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(121,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(121,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs(90,56): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs(90,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(182,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(182,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(182,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(182,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpGet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(260,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(260,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Controllers\FileController.cs(260,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Controllers\FileController.cs(260,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\SelectListHelper.cs(20,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\SelectListHelper.cs(20,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\SelectListHelper.cs(32,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\SelectListHelper.cs(32,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\SelectListHelper.cs(45,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\SelectListHelper.cs(45,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SelectList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(62,49): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(62,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(86,55): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(86,55): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(125,51): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(125,51): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(150,47): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(150,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(171,52): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\PagingControlHelper.cs(171,52): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(137,47): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(137,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(151,47): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(151,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(232,75): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(232,75): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(247,44): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(247,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(316,53): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(316,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(422,45): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\HtmlHelpers\DataGridHelper.cs(422,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(7,6): Error CS0641: Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute
Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(7,6): error CS0641: Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(10,48): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResultExecutingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(10,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResultExecutingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]
Solution\Solution\Solution\Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(10,30): Error CS0115: 'NoCacheAttribute.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext)': no suitable method found to override
Infrastructure\NoCacheAttribute.cs(10,30): error CS0115: 'NoCacheAttribute.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext)': no suitable method found to override [D:\TFSVSOWork\16\s\Solution\Solution\Solution\Solution.csproj]

[image]

Artifactory page
[image]

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of Build tasks/pipeline.

Comment: Screen shot added

Comment: the task nuget@2 supports restoring nuget packages into an explicit directory, i am not sure if this task is already shipped with your tfs version

Comment: Can you check this article, it shows feed concept [may help]   

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops

Comment: @Shalem this appears to be Azure DevOps 19 I am on Team Foundation Server 2017.  I am also using Artifactory Nugit Restore which works fine for non-ASP.Net applications.

Comment: @Shalem added another screen shot

Comment: @StephenM - Provided article works for TFS 2017 as well. Precisely, you could change version provided on top of Filter.

Comment: @StephenM: I assume you got wrong task in your build pipeline. Can you list down task names used in your build pipeline

Comment: Well I was wrong above, when I went to automate where I thought the Nugits went, I could not compile.  I now have the nugits in the 4 different directory levels and still no go.

Comment: @Shalem Process, Artifactory Nuget restore, Build Solution, test Assemblies, Publis symbols path, publish Artifact.

Comment: Could you try replace Nuget restore with Nuget installer task. This should help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191920/discussion-between-shalem-and-stephanm).